# Restricting a sender from withdrawing more than available balance

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am working on a simple bank smart contract example but I am having trouble getting the contract to restrict a sender from withdrawing more than the remaining balance. Here is my function within the contract:

```
function withdraw(uint withdrawAmount) public returns (uint) {
            assert(balances[msg.sender] >= withdrawAmount);
            balances[owner] -= withdrawAmount;
            emit LogWithdrawal(msg.sender, withdrawAmount, balances[msg.sender]);
            return balances[msg.sender];
    }
```

Here is the .js test:

```
it("should not be able to withdraw more than has been deposited", async() => {
    await instance.enroll({from: alice})
    await instance.deposit({from: alice, value: deposit})
    await catchRevert(instance.withdraw(deposit + 1, {from: alice}))
  })
```

I was thinking maybe assert(.....) but that didn't work so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is wrong because you compare `withdrawAmount` with `msg.sender`'s balance but decrease balance of `owner`, so `msg.sender`'s balance will not change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `require` instead of `assert` in this case. That being said your code seems ok, so make sure you are keeping track of the user balances correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not consistent, you check the balance for `msg.sender`, but withdraw from `owner`.

It should be the correct version:

```
function withdraw(uint withdrawAmount) public returns (uint) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= withdrawAmount);
    balances[msg.sender] -= withdrawAmount;
    emit LogWithdrawal(msg.sender, withdrawAmount, balances[msg.sender]);
    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```